# Error converting data type varchar to float on non varchar data type

Tags: sql, casting, coalesce

I've come across an issue (that I've partially solved) but can't seem to find a reason behind the failing in the first place.

I have a field in a table which holds a combination of alpha and numerical values. The field is a char(20) data type (which is wrong, but unchangeable) and holds either a **NULL value, 'Unknown' or the "numbers" 0, 50, 100**. The char field pads the values with trailing white space. This is a known and we can't do a thing about it.

To remove the Unknown values, we have a series of coalesce statements in place, and these two return the error message as per the title.

```
,coalesce(DHMCC.[HESA Module Total Proportion Taught], 'Missing')
,cast(isnull(DHMCC.[HESA Module Total Proportion Taught] ,'Missing') as varchar(10))
```

The query I have is why am I getting this error when I'm not converting a data type of varchar to float (or am I?)

Does anyone have an idea as to where to look next to try to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

The [`STR()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) accepts a float datatype as the first argument, therefore SQL Server is implicitly converting whatever you pass to this function, which in your case is the `CHAR(20)` column. Since `unknown` can't be converted to a float, you get the error. 
If you run the following with the actual execution plan enabled:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Col CHAR(20));
INSERT @T VALUES (NULL);

SELECT Result = ISNULL(STR(Col, 25, 0), 'Missing')
FROM @T
```

Then checkthe execution plan XML you will see the implicit conversion:

```
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="isnull(str(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(float(53),[Col],0),(25),(0)),'Missing')">
```

The simplest solution is probably to use a case expression and not bother with any conversion at all (only if you know you will only have the 5 values you listed:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Col CHAR(20));
INSERT @T VALUES (NULL), ('0'), ('50'), ('100');--, ('Unknown');

SELECT Result = CASE WHEN Col IS NULL OR Col = 'Unknown' THEN 'Missing' ELSE Col END
FROM @T;

Result
---------
Missing
0                   
50                  
100                 
Missing
```

If you really want the `STR()` function, you can make the conversion explicit, but use [`TRY_CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) so that anything that is not a float simply returns `NULL`:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Col CHAR(20));
INSERT @T VALUES (NULL), ('0'), ('50'), ('100');--, ('Unknown');

SELECT Result = ISNULL(STR(TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT, Col), 25, 0), 'Missing')
FROM @T

Result
------------
Missing
        0   
       50
      100
Missing
```

Although, since you the numbers you have stated are integers, I would be inclined to convert them to integers rather than floats:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Col CHAR(20));
INSERT @T VALUES (NULL), ('0'), ('50'), ('100'), ('Unknown');

SELECT Result = ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TRY_CONVERT(INT, Col)), 'Missing')
FROM @T;

Result
---------
Missing
0                   
50                  
100                 
Missing
```

Comment: In your edit you have removed any reference to `STR()`, are you using this or not? I am not able to repeat the error with the `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` expressions that you have posted. See demo here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e3cf1032d3208670b35f97425a33de83

Comment: Thanks Gareth, I realised that the STR() option isn't correct one, but was editing as you answered!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @GarethD

I've only just come across TRY_CONVERT and this seems like the better option, so thanks him for that pointer, also trying with TRY_CAST as well.

The data really should be held in a varchar field, it's referential and not for calculation, and this seems to work equally as well,

```
-- Declare @varText as varchar(16) = '10    '
-- Declare @varText as char(16) = 'Unknown'
-- Declare @varText as char(16) = ''

SELECT
ISNULL(NULLIF(TRY_CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(@varText)) as varchar(16)), ''), 'Missing') AS HESA
```

I've created this test scenario which works ok.